# Lucene highlighter hits all terms

Tags: search, lucene, highlighter

Here is the situation.

There is a field named "content" in the Lucene index document, and the "content" in each document has two values. For example:

- document1 - content: "gas and oil", "energy"
- document2 - content: "gas", "oil"

When I search "content:(+gas +oil)", both document1 and document2 are returned, that is expected.

The next step, I want to loop each content values for the hits,

- "gas and oil"
- "energy"
- "gas"
- "oil"

I used the highlighter, the purpose is to get "**gas** and **oil**" be returned because only this one "gas and oil" hit this query "(+gas +oil)".

But I actually get

- "**gas** and **oil**"
- "**gas**"
- "**oil**"

It seems that the query does not work on the highlighter, so when I use the query "(+gas +oil)" or the query "(gas oil)" to highlight, there is not much difference.

Did I use highlighter wrong? Is there a way to only get  "**gas** and **oil**"?

Code example I used

```
for (final String value : values) {
    final QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    final Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(scorer);
    highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(2000));
    final TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(value));
    final CachingTokenFilter filter = new CachingTokenFilter(tokenStream);
    final String highlightedText = highlighter.getBestFragment(filter, value);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(highlightedText)) {
      //TODO
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Highlighter is based on term, so the best way to solve this problem is to rebuild the index and organize it in a different way, that is:

```
document1 - content: "gas and oil"
document2 - content: "energy"
document3 - content: "gas"
document4 - content: "oil"
```

Therefore, when searching for "content:(+gas +oil)", only document1 will be hit.